# Can I use the verb 'forgo' in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forgo) says:

> **forgo** (*v.*) to not have or do something enjoyable:
>   *I shall have to forgo the pleasure of seeing you this week*.

So, can I use the verb ***forgo*** in this context?

For example, if one beats me and I don't want to beat him back, then can I say I '**forgo**' him?

Comment: You don't forgo your enemy: you forgo retaliation.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I say *"I **forgo** him"?*

You can't say that in this context. I also don't think we can "forgo" a person.

MW defines "forgo" as

> to give up the enjoyment or advantage of : do without

In your case, what you are giving up is the *enjoyment/satisfaction* of beating that person to a pulp. You have decided to just walk away instead of indulging in retaliation. As Anton Sherwood mentioned, *"You forgo retaliation"*.

However, I am not sure if you can even use "forgo" in that sense (i.e., *I had to forgo the pleasure of beating him to a pulp*). Correct me if I am wrong.

My reasoning is that to "forgo" something, you would need to **have** it in the first place or **experienced** it even if it was just one time.

Note how MW says *"to give up..."* in its definition. Unless you had fought this person (or any person) before and derived pleasure from it, I don't think you could say something like this: *I had to forgo the pleasure of beating him to a pulp*.

If you had never argued and won, you can't say *"I had to forgo the pleasure of winning the argument and proving that he is a fool - because I care about him."* because you have not experienced that pleasure/emotion before.

My reasoning is based on the fact that almost all examples in dictionaries use the term "forgo" when referring to something that one had possessed or had experienced.

> She is planning to forgo her right to a trial and simply plead guilty. {She had that right until she decided to plead guilty}
>
> I'll forgo dessert tonight—I'm trying to lose weight. {This person had desserts before}

Comment: It would be super helpful if the downvoter said why they thought this answer was not useful. It would allow me to improve it or learn from it.